# When is it worth using `remove` in R functions?

Tags: r, performance, function

What factors should I consider when deciding whether or not to `remove` a variable that will not be used again in a function?

Here's a noddy example:

```r
DivideByLower <- function (a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    tmp <- a
    a <- b
    b <- tmp
    remove(tmp) # When should I include this line?
  }

  # Return:
  a / b
}
```

I understand that `tmp` will be removed when the function finishes executing, but should I ever be concerned about removing it earlier?

Comment: Most often the answer will be no. If you don't have memory problems during function execution why bother?

Comment: Looks like you've already discovered an important lesson for writing R code: use functions! A lot of things like garbage collection are made much easier if you write functions to do the heavy lifting in your code instead of putting all your variables in the global environment. I agree with @RuiBarradas that you shouldn't worry about optimizing your performance in R unless you start having problems.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza It is also important to note that many members of the R Core Team have said along the years that it is usually not necessary to explicitly call `gc`, the memory will be released and garbage collection will occur when the variables cease to exist.

Comment: @RuiBarradas that's a good point. One advantage of functions is that intermediate variables are automatically deleted. For example, if I create `dataset_original`, `dataset_in_progress`, and `dataset_final` in the global environment, I'll have three copies of my dataset until I remove them. If I do the analysis in a function, the first two are deleted and only the third is returned. The pipe makes this less common, but sometimes I still end up having to create copies of my data for one reason or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Hadley Wickham's advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) :

> In some languages, you have to explicitly delete unused objects for
>   their memory to be returned. R uses an alternative approach: garbage
>   collection (or GC for short). GC automatically releases memory when an
>   object is no longer used. It does this by tracking how many names
>   point to each object, and when there are no names pointing to an
>   object, it deletes that object.

In the case you're describing garbage collection will release the memory.

In case the output of your function is another function, in which case Hadley names these functions respectively the *function factory* and the *manufactured function*, the variables created in the body of the *function factory* will be available in the enclosing environment of the *manufactured function*, and memory won't be freed.

More info, still in Hadley's book, can be found in the chapter about [function factories](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html).

```r
function_factory <- function(x){
  force(x)
  y <- "bar"
  fun <- function(z){
    sprintf("x, y, and z are all accessible and their values are '%s', '%s', and '%s'",
            x, y, z)
  }
  fun
}

manufactured_function <- function_factory("foo")
manufactured_function("baz")
#> [1] "x, y, and z are all accessible and their values are 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz'"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In this case, if you want to control which variables are available in the enclosing environment, or be sure you don't clutter your memory, you might want to remove unnecessary objects, either by using `rm` / `remove` as you did, or as I tend to prefer, wrapped in an `on.exit` statement.

Another case in which I might use rm is if I want to access variables from a parent environment without risk of them being overriden inside of the function, but in that case it's often possible and cleaner to use `eval.parent`.

```r
y <- 2
z <- 3
test0 <- function(x, var){
  y <- 1
  x + eval(substitute(var))
}

# opps, the value of y is the one defined in the body
test0(0, y)
#> [1] 1
test0(0, z)
#> [1] 3

# but it will work using eval.parent :
test1 <- function(x, var){
  y <- 1
  x + eval.parent(substitute(var))
}
test1(0, y)
#> [1] 2
test1(0, z)
#> [1] 3

# in some cases (better avoided), it can be easier/quick and dirty to do something like :
test2 <- function(x, var){
  y <- 1
  # whatever code using y
  rm(y)
  x + eval(substitute(var))
}
test2(0, y)
#> [1] 2
test2(0, z)
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>